# No instance for (Monoid [Char]) arising from a use of `mappend'

Tags: haskell

working with learn you Haskell functors applicative functors and monoids chapter and faced with a new problem, my code is here even though I tried to fix the problem I couldn't do it, my code is here:

```
class Monoid m where  
    mempty :: m  
    mappend :: m -> m -> m  

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a) where  
    mempty = Nothing  
    Nothing `mappend` m = m  
    m `mappend` Nothing = m  
    Just m1 `mappend` Just m2 = Just (m1 `mappend` m2)  

main = print $ Nothing `mappend` Just "andy"
```

and here is the error message that I got:

```
  No instance for (Monoid [Char]) arising from a use of `mappend'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monoid [Char])
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Nothing `mappend` Just "andy"'
    In the expression: print $ Nothing `mappend` Just "andy"
    In an equation for `main':
        main = print $ Nothing `mappend` Just "andy")
```

thank you in advance, Tamas

Comment: This is just saying that you don't have a Monoid instance for [Char] (or, String, if you prefer). Do you have any? You don't show it.

Comment: You have defined your own class `Monoid`, rather than importing `Data.Monoid`, where there *is* an instance of `Monoid` for `[a]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code hasn't provided a definition for `Monoid [a]` (the type of list doesn't matter). Normally, you would import `Data.Monoid`, where both the class `Monoid` and many useful instances are defined for you. It is trivial to write an instance, though, to fix your immediate problem. What does it mean to `mappend` two lists? You just concatenate the two lists.

```
instance Monoid [a] where
    mempty = []
    l1 `mappend` l2 = l1 ++ l2
```

Now you have the instance of `Monoid [a]` needed to fully implement the definition of `Monoid (Maybe [a])`.

Comment: thanks @chepner your answer is clear and works, Tamas

Comment: @bling5630, here's a challenge: write at least three different `Monoid` instances for lists that behave differently, and prove that each of them satisfies the monoid laws. Some of these instances will have constraints.